# difference between "to make a purchase" and "to purchase"

Tags: verbs, usage

What's the difference between "**to make a purchase**" and "**to purchase**"?

Are they just two different ways to say the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

***to make a purchase***

is abstract "why are you going to frank's shop" "oh to make a purchase"
but honestly I would say "to buy something". It leaves out what you are purchasing, there is no easy way to include the purchased item in the sentence.

This is just guessing but in this sentence purchase is a noun and make is the verb?

> **NOUN**
>
> 1.1 [*count noun*] A thing that has been bought.
>
> ‘she stowed her purchases in the car’

***to purchase***

requires a thing "why are you going to frank's shop" "oh to purchase more apples"

in this sentence purchase is the verb

> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT] 1 Acquire (something) by paying for it; buy.
>
> ‘Mr Gill spotted the manuscript at a local auction and purchased it
>   for £1,500’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/purchase

Answer (score 0):

*Purchase* often takes an object.

For example, I can I say,

> "I will purchase the tickets."

but I cannot say,

> "I will make a purchase the tickets."

Therefore, no, they are not simply two ways to say the same thing.

Comment: Is it valid to say "I will make a purchase *of* the tickets." or "I will make a purchase *for* the tickets." ?

Comment: @dan - "I will make a purchase of the tickets" is grammatical – but it's also unnecessarily wordy. I think most native speakers would simply say, "I'll buy the tickets."

Comment: Does "I will make a purchase of the tickets" sound more formal than "I'll buy the tickets."? Let's say you send a formal email to your manager in your company.

Comment: @dan - More wordy is not the same thing as more formal. If I wanted a more formal tone, I might say, "I will purchase the tickets," instead of "I'll buy the tickets," but I still wouldn't say, "I will make a purchase of the tickets." Using "make a purchase" like that sounds clumsy.